# Navbar with multidimentional array

Tags: php, twig

navbar.html.twig

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
{% for Links, Item in menu %}
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ Links }}">{{ Item }}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

server.php

```
$menu = [
  "Items" => array("Home", "Woman's Fashion", "Men's Fashion", "Accessories"),
  "Links" => array("/homepage", "/woman", "/men", "/accessories")
 ];


$params = [
  "name" => "Mr. Gadget",
  "title" => SITE_TITLE,
  "SITE_TITLE" => SITE_TITLE,
  "user" => "myName",
  "menu" => $menu
];

echo $twig->render('views/navbar.html.twig', $params);
```

This generates the output

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Items">Array
    </a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Links">Array
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So what I'm trying to do is basically generate a link and name for every menu item through an array

I've also tried putting a for loop in a for loop which creates 8 different items instead of just 4
How may I get both the name and link in the total count of items?

Comment: I believe you should prepare your data to be structured the way you need it before you pass it to the template. The less logic you have to do in the template, the better. So maybe a single array with names as keys and links as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate `menu.Items` or `menu.Links` and use the array key to pick an entry from the other array like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    {% for key, Item in menu.Items %}
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ menu.Links[key] }}">{{ Item }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[working example](https://twigfiddle.com/v6b9dn)